# How to offset a Mongoose sort query to start after a specific document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I currently have the following query to return the `count` most recently updated posts for a given `status`.

```
var query = Post.find()
  .where('status').equals(status)
  .sort('-updated')
  .limit(count);
```

If `status` was 'approved' and `count` was 3 then my result would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "test1",
    "updated": "2015-11-30T16:51:54.988Z",
    "status": "approved",
  },
  {
    "id": "test2",
    "updated": "2015-11-30T16:51:52.125Z",
    "status": "approved",
  },
  {
    "id": "test3",
    "updated": "2015-11-30T16:51:50.469Z",
    "status": "approved",
  }
]
```

I need to be able to specify an `id` to offset my results by.

For example if `status` was 'approved', `count` was 2 and the offset id was 'test1' the result should be:

```
[
  {
    "id": "test2",
    "updated": "2015-11-30T16:51:52.125Z",
    "status": "approved",
  },
  {
    "id": "test3",
    "updated": "2015-11-30T16:51:50.469Z",
    "status": "approved",
  }
]
```

So I'm ordering by the updated property but results should only start from the document after the offset id.

Comment: You should exclude the id from the query

Comment: @Michelem I was just using test1 as an example, this would need to work for any document which would mean excluding all ids updated before the date I want. I won't always know what they are as they're being added all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to exclude the id you don't need to skip them, there isn't any other solution:

```
var query = Post.find({
        $and: [{
            status: status
        }, {
            id: {
                $nin: ['test1']
            }
        }]
    })
    .sort('-updated')
    .limit(count);
```

With `$nin` you can exclude multiple `id` by using an array of ids like this:  `['test1', 'test2', 'etc...']`

Comment: Unfortunately this wont work because I'd need to exclude all ids updated before the date I want. I can't guarantee I'll know what they are as they're being added all the time.

Comment: I think you need to review your app's logic, because I don't think you are doing it well.

Comment: I think you're right, looks like I should be offsetting by the updated property rather than a specific document. Something like `where('updated').gt(aDateObject)`. I'll mark this as correct as it seems this is as close as you can get to what the title was asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot offset by a specific id but you can skip a certain number of documents by using `skip()`.

```
var query = Post.find()
    .where('status').equals(status)
    .sort('-updated')
    .limit(count)
    .skip(1); // <<< put the number of docs you want to skip here
```

If you want to skip all documents before and including a specific id, you'll have to do it manually (I can post code if it's what you need).

**Edit**

To skip all documents until you reach a specific document:

```
var query = Post.find()
    .where('status').equals(status)
    .sort('-updated')
    .limit(count);

var offsetId = 'test1';
var filteredDocs = [];

query.exec().then(function (docs) {
    var skipped = true;
    docs.forEach(function (doc) {
        if (skipped && doc.id == offsetId) skipped = false;
        if (!skipped) filteredDocs.push(doc);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't think they will provide reliable results.

Using `skip()` is unreliable because if a post is updated between queries it will be added to the beginning by `.sort('-updated')` which will throw off the skip number.

The second method won't work as `.limit(count)` will return the amount of posts i need. I'd have to query the entire collection to make sure I can skip to the desired document and return the correct amount.